# Save custom fields to member profile when creating member from CartThrob checkout

Tags: cartthrob, members

We have a very basic checkout form in which customers are saving their profiles. Using the [docs on CartThrob](http://cartthrob.com/docs/tags_detail/checkout_form/#create_user) I've got it all working, but only the username/email fields are going through to EE member. Is there a way to pass the other fields over as well? (i.e. first name, last name, phone, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you have mapped your member fields by going to CartThrob > Settings > Members and map your order fields to your custom member fields or channel fields if you are using Profile:Edit or ZooVisitor.